# excel bar chart axis customisation

Tags: excel, charts

I have a stacked bar chart in excel. This is made up of positive and negative comments. I can get the negative topic names down one side of the axis but can't work out how to get the positive down the right hand side of the chart?

Example the 92% and the 8% are in my stacked bar chart:

Customer service: good [92% 8%] Customer service: poor

I've attached an image below to make it clearer.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073101/stacked-bar-chart-custom-format/29669512#29669512 which has a couple answers.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this as output?
[image]

In this case you just need to rename the series.
[image]

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response. What I need is for example where you have the name service1: Good and then where the red section finishes have service1: poor?

Comment: Hi, can anyone help with this. I basically need a secondary access with corresponding Good version. At the moment I can only get the poor version on the x axis?